# Setting routerLink with interpolation

Tags: angular

I am developing an app in Angular 5

in my ts file I am setting an string array as

```
breadCumbSetter.bCumb = [
  {name:'Operation',route:'/operation'},
];
```

and in my view I am using it like below

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item">
          <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item" *ngFor="let item of breadCumbSetter.bCumb">
          <a [routerLink]="['"+{{item.route}}+"']">{{item.name}}</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
```

I am facing problem in

```
<a [routerLink]="['"+{{item.route}}+"']">{{item.name}}</a>
```

I cant set route value in routerLink , I also tried many suggestion that i found on web ,

```
  [routerLink]="item.route"
  routerLink=[item.route]
```

but nothing works ,

How can I set routerLink value through interpolation or is there any other way to do it inside a *ngFor loop ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to understand how `@Input`s work in Angular, and what `routerLink` accepts.

`routerLink` can either accept a full string, which is an absolute router URL, or an array of strings and numbers, which is relative to your current route (unless the first item starts with a `/`)

For the `@Input`s :

- `routerLink="foo"` means you're sending `'foo'` as a string to the input
- `[routerLink]="foo"` means you're sending a variable called `foo` to the input
- `routerLink="{{foo}}"` means you're sending a variable called `foo` to the input
- `[routerLink]="'foo'"` means you're sending `'foo'` as a string to the input
- `[routerLink]="[foo]"` means you're sending an array of one item, being the `foo` variable, to the input

Now that this is said, the correct syntax for your case should be

```
[routerLink]="[item.route]"
```

You might think that it is equivalent to

```
[routerLink]="['"+{{item.route}}+"']"
```

But it isn't. This won't work because you're using the variable notation (`[routerLink]`) along with extrapolation (`{{item.route}}`). You can use either of them, but not both.

Comment: first it did not work , second you suggesting to use last option shown by you - to pass an array of one item , but item.route is not an array of one item it itself a single value from array

Comment: `item.route` is a string, `[item.route]` is an array of a single string. If it doesn't work, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I wonder how it is not Minimal , Complete and Verifiable example . By the way thanks for your help . I will dig some deep on official documentation .

Comment: It is Minimal, not Complete (having your route configuration, having your TS code and full HTML code), it isn't Verifiable (no sandbox to reproduce the issue). You can dig as much as you want, this is the summary of it. So either dig in the documentation, or provide a [mcve] so that people on SOF can help you. But if you go into the documentation, the please delete your question, as it isn't coping with the requirements of [ask].

Comment: buddy , I can provide you  my route configuration and my TS code but after seeing that all you gonna say is -'Now its not minimal' . Don't jump in an infinite loop

Comment: Cant delete now , its not allowed now for this question

Comment: I don't need sassy comments or bad faith. If you're looking for help, you listen to the people that are here to help you, and you provide what they ask to help you. If you don't want to, then don't post a question. I have 15K reputation, you have 100. I have 2.5 years of experience in Angular, you probably don't have that much. If you don't want help, then don't ask for it.

Comment: And for your information, having your route config would tell me if the routes you want to reach are children of `dashboard`, or on the same level (which is different). Having your TS would tell me if you changed your variable value, meaning that you indeed can't access the desired route. Finally, having a sandbox could tell me exactly your issue, and I could correct it **for you**.

Comment: I did not said anything wrong here neither have any intention to do something like that , yes people come here to help and more than that to share their programming experience but who is asking about your rating or your experience ?

Comment: `I can provide you my route configuration and my TS code but after seeing that all you gonna say is -'Now its not minimal' . Don't jump in an infinite loop`. Sass and bad faith. And I'm talking about reputation to tell you I know what a [mcve] is, and about experience to tell you I know this is how Angular works. Anyway, I'm not here to argue, you clearly don't want help, I'm moving out. Notify me when you decide to change your mind.